# Npgsql 42601: syntax error at or near (

Tags: postgresql, ado.net, npgsql

I've encountered a problem while trying to execute following command using Npgsql from ADO.NET:

```js
  DO
  $do$
  BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'public' AND TABLE_NAME = 'event_journal') THEN
      CREATE TABLE public.event_journal (
          id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
          persistence_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
          sequence_nr BIGINT NOT NULL,
          is_deleted BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
          created_at BIGINT NOT NULL,
          manifest VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
          payload BYTEA NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT event_journal_uq UNIQUE (persistence_id, sequence_nr)
      );
      CREATE INDEX event_journal_sequence_nr_idx ON public.event_journal(sequence_nr);
      CREATE INDEX event_journal_created_at_idx ON public.event_journal(created_at);
  END IF;
  END
  $do$
```

It's a standard syntax error *42601: syntax error at or near (* with position pointing out at first line of a create table statement. What's strange for me, running that SQL directly against the Postgres database executes correctly without any errors.

**Npgsql version:** 3.0.7
**PostgreSQL version:** 9.4.5, 64-bit
**.NET version:** 4.5 (Windows 8.1 CLR)

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using the `IF NOT EXISTS` option on your `CREATE TABLE` instead?

Comment: I want to have all three statements executed together or none of them. Besides using CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS also doesn't work and throws the same exception.

Comment: It works fine in `"PostgreSQL 9.5.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.3.1-13ubuntu3) 5.3.1 20160330, 64-bit"`

Comment: mnv Are you talking about running it directly on the database (which as I mentioned works fine) or by using ADO.NET Npgsql library?